# Android API get attribute as list or null

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I'm creating an API that return Vaccination Info of people. The code below is that I'm getting list of vaccination IDs. If people injected 1 or more, the API working fine, I get a list as expected. Vice versa, if they haven't injected, the data on server is null. In that case, when I make an API call I will get the error that vaccinationInfoList is null, but it's still have the size 1. I tried as below to locate the error but it's cannot catch any exception.

```
try {
    Response<List<Vaccination_info>> res = call.execute();
    Log.v("RES" , String.valueOf(res));
    if (res.body() != null){
        try {
            vaccinationInfoList = res.body();
        }
        catch (Exception n){
            Log.v("ExceptionN" , String.valueOf(n));
        }
    } else {
            Log.v("NULL" , "NULL");
     }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.v("VACC", String.valueOf(vaccinationInfoList.size()));
```

Can someone recommend me a solution or a different aproach? Thanks so much

Comment: Not enough info here to debug.  Where are you setting vaccinationInfoList body ==null?  Because in that case it won't be set.  Also, what is the response from the server?  Is the server sending down an array of size 1 regardless?

Comment: No, I tested with Postman and receive the value of that attribute is null, not the empty array list

Answer (score 1):

If you have access and can change api response  so change response from `null` to empty array list `[]`

If not You can use `com.google.gson.JsonElement`